# How to Display Text in the System Tray

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've seen in some Microsoft WP apps where they display text in the system tray along with the time, and then when the user taps the system tray the text disappears and the normal system tray data (signal, power, etc) comes down and is displayed. An example of this would be the bing weather app on WP8. I'd like to be able to implement the same feature in an app I am creating, where the user always sees some sort of system tray data, such as time with the name of the app, or the full system tray display that can normally be viewed. Is this possible for developers or is this some sort of thing only Microsoft has the ability to do? To note, I do not mean displaying text while a progress bar is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code would work for you:

```
ProgressIndicator prog = new ProgressIndicator();
prog.IsIndeterminate = false;
prog.Text = "Your text";
prog.IsVisible = true;
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, prog);
```

ProgressIndicator  would need

using Microsoft.Phone.Shell; namespace